# Can an M42 mount be used to attach an A-mount Sony camera to a NexStar telescope?

Tags: astrophotography, sony, adapter

Do the NexStar-series telescopes allow for a camera to be attached using an M42 adapter?

Answer (score 1):

The flange focal length of Sony A-mount is 44.50 mm, which is shorter than 45.46 mm of M42, so you only need an adapter in theory.